# Linq select Item where it is equal to ID in another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am not sure how possible this is but I have two tables and I want to grab a value from table 2 via the value of table 1.

Table 1 has the a Foreign Key called "rank" which is an `int`. Table 2 has a value called "name" which is a `string`. Now Table 1's "rank" correlates to Table 2's "ID".

So when I say

`var result = 
     db.Table1.Select(x => new { x.name, x.rank }).ToList(); 
//Bob - 2`

I really want to say something like

`var result = 
     db.Table1.Select(x => new { x.name, Table2.rank.Where(ID == x.rank) }).ToList(); 
//Bob - Gold`

I am still new to LINQ though and I am not sure how to get `rank`'s string value from the other table within a query like this.

**EDIT**

Tables I am using and their relational values.

User: ID (PK), s1elo (FK to PastElos), champ (FK to ChampionList), elo (FK to EloList)

PastElo: ID (PK), Rank

ChampionList: ID (PK), name

EloList: ID (PK), Rank

Working example for Users and PastElo

`var result = 
     db.Users.Join(db.PastEloes, 
              x => x.s1elo, y => y.ID, (x, y) 
                => new { y.Rank, x.name, x.other_items_in_Users }).ToList();`

Note: PastElo is PastEloe's due to EF making everything plural when I synced up my DB, thus why User is also Users, I think that is referred to as the "context".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
var result = db.Table1.Join(db.Table2, 
                            x=>x.rank, 
                            y=>y.ID, 
                           (x,y) => new { x.rank, y.Name }).ToList();
```

In the above linq query we make a `Join` between the two tables, `Table1` and `Table2` based on the association and then we select that we want.

Another way you could try to write this query would be the following:

```
var result = (from t1 in db.Table1
             join t2 in db.Table2
             on t1.rank equals t2.ID
             select new { t1.rank, t2.Name, }).ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting! I shall give it a try! Is it possible to join multiple tables btw? In theory I actually reference to 3 different tables to get some side info that is stored separately for looser coupling of the data. So is it possible to Join multiple tables?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible. If you could post an example of your tables, I could help.

Comment: @Austin, could you please what exactly, which is the values you want to select from your tables in your first post?

Comment: Sure I will post the working one I got from your example, one second

Comment: Austin please give me a couple of a hours and i will be back. Thanks for being patient!

Comment: I "think" I figured it out, I can post what I found later. Thanks! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59538/discussion-between-christos-and-austin).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to include your Database relationships in your C# entities. You could use EntityRef here. See the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-map-database-relationships